# Построение графика функции после интегрирования

Tags: python, массивы

Нужно построить график для уравнения на скрине при разных значениях t, [image: Картинка]

Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate
import scipy
P0=1
L1=-4
L=1
L2=4
d=0.01
x=np.arange(L1,L2,d)
E=1
t_1=0.1
t_2=0.5
t_3=1
t_4=2
a=1
u=1
def make_T(t):
    Fo=a*t/(L*L)
    k=u*L/(2*a)
    def f(x):
        return scipy.special.erfc((1-2*k*Fo*(1-x)/(2*np.sqrt(Fo*(1-x)))-scipy.special.erfc(k*np.sqrt(Fo*(1-x)))))
    v, err = integrate.quad(f, 0, 1)
    Txt = k*Fo*v
    T_otnos = Txt/(P0*E)
    return(T_otnos)
Txt_1=make_T(t_1)
Txt_2=make_T(t_2)
Txt_3=make_T(t_3)
Txt_4=make_T(t_4)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, Txt_1, label = 'u*t ='+str(t_1))
ax.plot(x, Txt_2, label = 'u*t ='+str(t_2))
ax.plot(x, Txt_3, label = 'u*t='+str(t_3))
ax.plot(x, Txt_4, label = 'u*t ='+str(t_4))
ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='dT/(E*dP)',
title='dT/(E*dP)')
ax.grid()
legend = ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

На выходе эта ошибка: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (800,) and (1,). В чем может заключаться проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так у вас в качестве `y` везде ровно одно число. А нужен вектор.

В общем, я так понимаю, что в качестве `x` у вас выступает `L`. Что-то осмысленное получилось если сделать так, перебрав в качестве параметра `L` значения из `x` (показываю только изменённые/добавленные строки):

```py
def make_T(t, L):
    ...

Txt_1 = []
Txt_2 = []
Txt_3 = []
Txt_4 = []

for L in x:
    Txt_1.append(make_T(t_1, L))
    Txt_2.append(make_T(t_2, L))
    Txt_3.append(make_T(t_3, L))
    Txt_4.append(make_T(t_4, L))
```

Т.е. я изменяю `L` в цикле от `L1` до `L2`. Рисунок, правда, слился в одинаковые линии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если менять `d`, может получиться что-то другое.

Например, при `d = 0.3`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверняка, можно получить сразу вектор результата, без циклов, но мне уже лень думать.

Comment: Да, с размерностями я не совсем все правильно сделал, большое спасибо! Однако не совсем ясно поведение графиков относительно выбора шага. Интуитивно кажется, что изображение должно просто становиться чуть более гладким, а не кардинально менять свои значения, в чем здесь загвоздка?

Comment: Я недоразобрался, но у меня сложилось впечатление, что возле 0 эта штука неустойчива и стремится то ли к минус бесконечности, то ли к плюс - как попасть. И поэтому графики выходят такие странные.

Comment: Да, число Фурье при выборе определенного шага и попытке его рассчитать в области нуля уходила в большие значения, потому вставил эти правки:
tmp_cnst = 0.1; # это значение +- от 0 которого x не будет иметь значения
min_x_minus = 0 - tmp_cnst
min_x_plus = 0 + tmp_cnst
x1=np.arange(L1,min_x_minus,d)
x2=np.arange(min_x_plus,L2,d)
x=np.hstack((x1,x2))
Вместо x=np.arange(L1, L2, d)